# Acessing weblogs from apache webserver

Tags: php

As i'm new to php and apache web programming, i am a bit confuse of how to get access to the weblogs from the server.. i am currently doing a project on adaptive websites and i need to get hold of the weblogs to create adaptation of the website. i actually want to gain access where i will be able to store it in a data base.

can someone please guide me in the direction i'm seeking.... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The location of access.log depends on the various server installations.

There is an Apache mod for logging to database: [mod_log_sql](http://www.outoforder.cc/projects/apache/mod_log_sql/).
Here is described [why is better to log via the webserver](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/10825_3376671_4/Advanced-Logging-Techniques-With-Apache.htm) instead of processing the log file directly.

Comment: hey ... thanks for ur suggestion.... but would it be better to use a software type to capture the logs and perform stats for me..
thanks